# Allowing background audio with Swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, audiokit

I want to allow background audio while the app is not in focus. I currently have this code, which should allow that:

```
do {
    try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playback, with: .mixWithOthers)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
```

I also have the setting 'Audio, Airplay and Picture in Picture' enabled in capabilities settings. However, when I press the home button on my device the audio doesn't keep playing. What am I doing wrong? I am using [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io/) to produce sounds if that matters.

I am using a singleton to house all of the AudioKit components which I named AudioPlayer.swift. Here is what I have in my AudioPlayer.swift singleton file:

```
class AudioPlayer: NSObject {
    var currentFrequency = String()
    var soundIsPlaying = false

    var leftOscillator = AKOscillator()
    var rightOscillator = AKOscillator()

    var rain = try! AKAudioFile()
    var rainPlayer: AKAudioPlayer!

    var envelope = AKAmplitudeEnvelope()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        do {
            try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playback, with: .mixWithOthers)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true

        AudioKit.output = envelope
        AudioKit.start()
    }

    func setupFrequency(left: AKOscillator, right: AKOscillator, frequency: String) {
        currentFrequency = frequency

        leftOscillator = left
        rightOscillator = right

        let leftPanner = AKPanner(leftOscillator)
        leftPanner.pan = -1

        let rightPanner = AKPanner(rightOscillator)
        rightPanner.pan = 1

        //Set up rain and rainPlayer
        do { 
            rain = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "rain.wav")
            rainPlayer = try AKAudioPlayer(file: rain, looping: true, deferBuffering: false, completionHandler: nil)
        } catch { print(error) }

        let mixer = AKMixer(leftPanner, rightPanner, rainPlayer)

        //Put mixer in sound envelope
        envelope = AKAmplitudeEnvelope(mixer)
        envelope.attackDuration = 2.0
        envelope.decayDuration = 0
        envelope.sustainLevel = 1
        envelope.releaseDuration = 0.2

        //Start AudioKit stuff
        AudioKit.output = envelope
        AudioKit.start()
        leftOscillator.start()
        rightOscillator.start()
        rainPlayer.start()
        envelope.start()
        soundIsPlaying = true
    }
}
```

And here is an example of one of my sound effect view controllers, which reference the AudioKit singleton to send it a certain frequency (I have about a dozen of these view controllers, each with its own frequency settings):

```
class CalmView: UIViewController {
    let leftOscillator = AKOscillator()
    let rightOscillator = AKOscillator()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        leftOscillator.amplitude = 0.3
        leftOscillator.frequency = 220

        rightOscillator.amplitude = 0.3
        rightOscillator.frequency = 230
    }

    @IBAction func playSound(_ sender: Any) {
        if shared.soundIsPlaying == false {
            AudioKit.stop()
            shared.setupFrequency(left: leftOscillator, right: rightOscillator, frequency: "Calm")
        } else if shared.soundIsPlaying == true && shared.currentFrequency != "Calm" {
            AudioKit.stop()
            shared.leftOscillator.stop()
            shared.rightOscillator.stop()
            shared.rainPlayer.stop()
            shared.envelope.stop()
            shared.setupFrequency(left: leftOscillator, right: rightOscillator, frequency: "Calm")
        } else {
            shared.soundIsPlaying = false
            shared.envelope.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

I instantiated the AudioPlayer singleton in my ViewController.swift file.

Comment: There's a fine line between having enough code and having too much. The question you asked has been answered below.  You appear to have things set up correctly.  Test the AudioKit example SongProcessor to see if it behaves the way it should and then compare your code to it.  There are no shortcuts and easy solutions sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when you are doing your configuration in relation to when AudioKit is started.  If you're using AudioKit you should be using its AKSettings to manage your session category.  Basically not only the playback category but also mixWithOthers.  By default, does this:

```
/// Set the audio session type
@objc open static func setSession(category: SessionCategory,
                            with options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions = [.mixWithOthers]) throws {
```

So you'd do something like this in your ViewController:

```
    do {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    } catch {
        print("Errored setting category.")
    }
```

So I think its a matter of getting that straight. It might also help to have inter-app audio set up.  If you still have trouble and provide more information, I can help more, but this is as good an answer as I can muster based on the info you've given so far.

Comment: Should I start AudioKit after these settings have been set up or before? Right now I have this code in my ViewController.swift but I start AudioKit in another view controller. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: AudioKit will probably override the setting you're doing if you do them first. I don't suggest doing any audio in view controllers.  Instead, create a singleton class for your audio - sometimes we'll call it the engine or the conductor, and refer to it from all your view controllers.  You don't want to have the view controller life cycle have any effect on the state of your audio engine.

Comment: I have my audio player in a singleton and I moved the code from my original post into it, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Well, I just used the code from your updated question verbatim to prove that the SongProcessor example from AudioKit plays in the background, so my answer is valid to your question.  Perhaps you are doing something else wrong.  https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/0dcde9b4865133f61a6fd70c2e921c75aeb9b8e4

Comment: Is there a specific spot I am supposed to put this code? I copied the highlighted portion from your link and put it in my AudioPlayer.swift singleton, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, the right spot.You're not providing the code so its impossible to answer. I gave you a working example with SongProcessor. This should be sufficient.